# DB2 to MSSQL migration error in app "org.hibernate.MappingException:Could not instantiate id generator" and "Dialect does not support sequences"

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, orm, mssql-jdbc

We are migrating from DB2 to MSSQL DB, and am at the stage of configuring our app which is on Hibernate to connect to the MSSQL DB. Connection to the MSSQL DB has been established, but these 2 errors are being thrown up and the app initialization fails:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException:Could not instantiate id generator
```

and

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException:Dialect does not support sequences
```

Our hibernate configuration is xml based, and all the table configurations are similar and as below:
`<generator class="assigned">`
or
`<generator class="native">`
Most of the solutions I have read have to deal with annotation styles configs, which we cannot move over to. What should be the equivalent xml configuration of GENERATOR strategy AUTO or IDENTITY? MSSQL supposedly also does not support sequences in this context, but then doesn't a part of the purpose of Hibernate where it is supposed to be a ORM where you just need to change connections params, and bingo, connected to another DB system, fails?

Comment: Seems the Hibernate dialect is a bit outdated. SQL Server has been supporting sequences for quite some time now

Comment: You mean updating Hibernate may work? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: SQL Server 2012 supported sequences, so yes, sounds like you need to update Hibernate.

Comment: Okay, is there a known version of Hibernate which starts supporting sequences of MSSQL?

Comment: As of Hibernate 4.3 as you can see here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/5981fc19b5ca4b0bba9669f8f4092b2aa0ec2257

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBeikov, upgrading Hibernate was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSSQL DB being used is version 15 (2019), which needs an upgraded Dialect. Upgrading Hibernate to 4.3.9.Final from 3.2.5.ga, and changing dialect to this solved the problem, without any other changes to the sequences or mapping files

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect"</prop>
```